# Why didn't Cell teleport to Earth after his death?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

After Cell blew up, he said he learned the instant transmission technique from Goku, using which he teleported back to Earth from the King Kai's planet

So once he's killed by Gohan he still could have came back right???

Why didn't he come back???

Answer (score 6):

When Cell was killed by Gohan, he was just that, *killed.* He was actually dead this time, and was sent to King Yama to be judged. Once you're dead, you can't just teleport back to Earth. You have to either be revived or given temporary rights to be in the physical world. As Cell met neither of these requirements, he had no way to go back to Earth, using Instant Transmission or otherwise, since there is concept of Heaven and Hell in the Otherworld: once a person is sent to Hell, he cannot just come out unless he is purified or the boundaries of Hell itself are broken by other means. Which is why Goku was able to bend the rules of Otherworld but the evil characters could not.

Comment: No you are wrong. In the DBZ movie, where Super Brolly is cloned and unleashed in earth, Goku will teleport himself from King Kai planet even when he was dead after fighting Cell. Also King Kai will be mad that Goku keeps breaking the rules

Comment: @mani_nz This also happened in the movie Bojack Unbound. Goku can teleport to the living world for a short time, although he is not supposed to. The reason Cell couldn't teleport is because he, unlike Goku, lost his body when he died.

Comment: Wrong again. Cell had his body. If you remember the Super android 17 saga, cell and freiza were fighting goku

Comment: Just wanted to mention that the DBZ movies aren't cannon

Answer (score 1):

I'd quote a few excerpts from the relevant episodes to clear your doubt.

First, to explain how Cell was able to come back after being teleported by Goku to King Kai's planet. [Episode 189 : Cell Returns](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Cell_Returns!)(emphasis mine)

> After killing Future Trunks, **Cell explains how he survived after the explosion of King Kai's planet. Cell explains that his central nucleus had survived, allowing him to regenerate, and that his cells had retained the knowledge of his perfect power. Being of Saiyan genetics, Cell also reveals to have received a Zenkai, a power up for recovering from a near fatal injury.** After hearing about how Cell survived, Gohan powers up to his maximum, and is ready to avenge his father's death.

Next to explain why he wasn't able to re-generate when Gohan and Goku killed him with their Kamehamehas. [Episode 191: Save the World](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Save_the_World)(emphasis mine)

> With Goku saying "NOW'S YOUR CHANCE!" to his son, Gohan screams and releases all of his energy at Cell. **Cell then screams as he is destroyed by the attack. The energy wave is strong enough to vaporize every cell in his body, preventing Cell's regeneration. Cell is finally destroyed once and for all, and the Earth is safe again.**

So as you can see, the first time when Cell self-destructed, his central nucleus had survived that blow and he was able to regenerate and come back, but the second time, the Kamehamehas of Goku and Gohan combined was so great that every single cell of Cell was destroyed and he was gone for good. Thus, he couldn't regenerate and come back.

Note that, if instant transmission was all that was required for a dead man to return back to Earth, Goku could have done that almost always. After anybody dies, they go to the [Other World](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Other_World) and to come back from there, you either need to be brought back to life by using the Dragon balls or be granted *Temporal revival energy*. Since Cell was neither brought back to life nor was granted any temporal revival energy, he stayed in the Other World post his death.

Comment: No you are wrong. In the DBZ movie, where Super Brolly is cloned and unleashed in earth, Goku will teleport himself from King Kai planet even when he was dead after fighting Cell.

Also King Kai will be mad that Goku keeps breaking the rules.

Comment: @mani_nz - Wrong. Goku isn't dead at that time. He is still alive and this movie happens between the episodes 176 and 177. [Have a look at the wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_Broly_-_The_Legendary_Super_Saiyan).

Comment: Nope. Check this link,
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_x-uN50iZwI

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Cell could not return back to earth after Gohan destroyed his body is that hell has a barrier around it that makes it so no one can leave. When Goku is dead, he is in the spirit world and can use instant transmission to go back and forth.

Cell was able to use the instant transmission technique when Goku grabbed him and used it to get him away from earth. The explosion from Cell didn't completely destroy him, so he could rebuild himself into perfect form.

Once Gohan used his full power to destroy Cell, no part of him was left in the living world for him to regenerate back to. Cell was actually was dead. Cell was instantly transferred to hell once he died. He didn't go to the spirit world and see king Yema or anything; he just went straight there.

Once he is in there, he cannot leave due to the fact that the barrier around hell made it so no one could leave. For someone to leave hell, someone has to make a hole in the barrier like in the movie Super Android 17.

When Goku is in hell trying to get out in the movie he cannot since the barrier is up. Goku tried multiple times to get out without the help of Piccolo. When he created the bridge with Piccolo, it caused a hole in the barrier and he was able to use instant transmission out of hell and back to earth.